# I made my own webapp, how to change the title (or whatever)?

Tags: webapps

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Vostro 3546.
Here is my webapp code in `/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/sketchboard.png`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Sketchboard
GenericName=Sketchboard
Comment=Sketchboard desktop webapp
Icon=/usr/sketchboard.png
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://sketchboard.me/
Actions=
MimeType=text/plain;
Categories=Application;Network;Graphics;
Keywords=Sketchboard;webapp;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=sketchboard.me
```

Here is my picture:

[image: sketchboard]
As you see, I have emphasised the webapp title (or whatever we say it.) Sometimes the link is also displayed there.
I only want to see "Sketchboard" written there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the window is handled by [`<title>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp) HTML element, after all you're actually opening a website, not a local standalone app. So this is a browser-side thing and I don't think it's possible to modify title from desktop entry.

To control the title, you can use `document.title` of JavaScript and override the default title. To test things,

- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open *Developer tools* once the "webapp" starts.
- Navigate to *Console*.
- Run

  ```js
  document.title="My title for Sketchboard"
  ```

If you're satisfied with the result, you can use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and create an userscript in order to override the title whenever you open the webapp or website. The userscript would look like

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sketchboard
// @version      0.1
// @description  Window title modifier for Sketchboard
// @author       You
// @match        *sketchboard.me/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.title="Modified Title"
})();
```

Comment: Could you please suggest a way without any installation of apps or extensions?

Comment: @GopalS Since this is to be done from browser side only and I already mentioned that *I don't think it's possible to modify title from desktop entry.*